# Constructing an array from a text file in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have an annoying report output (curse be to HP) that is not something I can shape by a query - it's all or nothing more or less. I would like to take two lines from each "chunk" of output and construct an array from this. I figured it would be a simple split() operation but no such luck. A sample of the output is as so:

```
Medium identifier : 1800010a:54bceddd:1d8c:0007

Medium label             : [ARJ170L6] ARJ170L6
Location                 : [TapeLibrary:    24]
Medium Owner             : wfukut01
Status                   : Poor
Blocks used  [KB]        : 2827596544
Blocks total [KB]        : 2827596544
Usable space [KB]        : 1024
Number of writes         : 16
Number of overwrites     : 4
Number of errors         : 0
Medium initialized       : 19 January 2015, 11:43:32
Last write               : 26 April 2016, 21:02:12
Last access              : 26 April 2016, 21:02:12
Last overwrite           : 24 April 2016, 04:48:55
Protected                : Permanent
Write-protected          : No


Medium identifier : 1800010a:550aa81e:3a0c:0006

Medium label             : [ARJ214L6] ARJ214L6
Location                 : External
Medium Owner             : wfukut01
Status                   : Poor
Blocks used  [KB]        : 2904963584
Blocks total [KB]        : 2904963584
Usable space [KB]        : 0
Number of writes         : 9
Number of overwrites     : 7
Number of errors         : 0
Medium initialized       : 19 March 2015, 10:42:45
Last write               : 30 April 2016, 22:14:19
Last access              : 30 April 2016, 22:14:19
Last overwrite           : 29 April 2016, 13:41:35
Protected                : Permanent
Write-protected          : No
```

What would be ideal is if the final output of this work would create an array somewhat similar to this:

```
Location                     UsableSpace
---------                    -------------
External                     0
TapeLibrary                  1024
```

So I can (for example) query the output so that I can do operations on the data within the array:

```
$myvar | where-object { $_.Location -eq "TapeLibrary" }
```

Perhaps there are better approaches? I would be more than happy to hear them!

Comment: What command is generating that output?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use the command itself and `select` certain properties. If the command is a powershell cmdlet, it should return an **Object**.

```
$output = Some-HPCommand | select 'Medium label', 'Location'
```

Then you can access specific properties:

```
$output.'Medium label'
$output.Location
```

If you can provide the *exact* command, I can write this more accurately.

The biggest issue when people are learning powershell is they treat output like a *String*... Everything in PowerShell is object-oriented, and once you begin to think in terms of *Objects*, it becomes much easier to process data; in other words, always try to handle output as objects or arrays of objects. It will make your life a hell of a lot easier.

Comment: I wish that were the case. This is absolutely not a PS cmdlet. Just a big ole bunch of strings.

Answer (score 2):

If the command is not a Powershell cmdlet like Kolob Canyon's answer then you would need to parse the text. Here's an inelegant example using `-match` and regex to find the lines with `Location` and `Usable space [KB]` and find the word characters after the colon.

```
((Get-Content C:\Example.txt -Raw) -split 'Medium identifier') | ForEach-Object {
    [void]($_ -match 'Location\s+:\s(.*?(\w+).*)\r')
    $Location = @($Matches.values | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch '\W'})[0]
    [void]($_ -match 'Usable\sspace\s\[KB\]\s+:\s(.*?(\w+).*)\r')
    $UsableSpace = @($Matches.values | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch '\W'})[0]
    if ($Location -or $UsableSpace){
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Location = $Location
            UsableSpace = $UsableSpace
        }
    }
}
```

As this is extremely fragile and inelegant, it's much better to interact with an object where ever possible.

Comment: I was also wondering (since the output is *key*:*value* pairs) if he could just surround the output in `{}` and run `ConvertFrom-Json` to convert it to an object

Comment: @KolobCanyon That's a great idea. But I think there would be a lot of escaping that would have to be done. e.g. `Medium label = > 'Medium Label'`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking too

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the data is as regular as it looks, you could use multiple assignment to extract the data from the array as in:

```
$data = 1, 2, "ignore me", 3, 10, 22, "ignore", 30
$first, $second, $null, $third, $data = $data
```

where the first, second and fourth array elements go into the variables, "ignore me" gets discarded in `$null` and the remaining data goes back into data. In your case, this would look like:

```
# Read the file into an array
$data = Get-Content data.txt

# Utility to fix up the data row
function FixUp ($s)
{
    ($s -split ' : ')[1].Trim()
}

# Loop until all of the data is processed
while ($data)
{
    # Extract the current record using multiple assignment
    # $null is used to eat the blank lines
    $identifier,$null,$label,$location,$owner,$status,
        $used,$total,$space,$writes,$overwrites,
        $errors, $initialized, $lastwrite, $lastaccess,
        $lastOverwrite, $protected, $writeprotected,
        $null, $null, $data = $data

    # Convert it into a custom object 
    [PSCustomObject] [ordered] @{
        Identifier   = fixup $identifier
        Label        = fixup $label
        location     = fixup $location
        Owner        = fixup $owner
        Status       = fixup $status
        Used         = fixup $used
        Total        = fixup $total
        Space        = fixup $space
        Write        = fixup $writes
        OverWrites   = fixup $overwrites
        Errors       = fixup $errors
        Initialized  = fixup $initialized
        LastWrite    = [datetime] (fixup $lastwrite)
        LastAccess   = [datetime] (fixup $lastaccess)
        LastOverWrite = [datetime] (fixup $lastOverwrite)
        Protected    = fixup $protected
        WriteProtected = fixup $writeprotected
    }
}
```

Once you have the data extracted, you can format it any way you want

Comment: Like that very much +1. All datetimes get properly casted. If you put the whole `while` into a new variable and group/measure -sum space that var you get the desired end result.

Answer (score 2):

That looks a very regular pattern, so I'd say there are three typical approaches to this.

First: your own bucket-fill-trigger-empty parser, load lines in until you reach the next trigger ("Medium identifier"), then empty out the bucket to the pipeline and start a new one.

Something like:

```
$bucket = @{}

foreach ($line in Get-Content -LiteralPath C:\path\data.txt)
{
    # if full, empty bucket to pipeline
    if ($line -match '^Medium identifier')
    {
        [PSCustomObject]$bucket
        $bucket = @{}
    }

    # add line to bucket (unless it's blank)
    if (-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($line))
    {
        $left, $right = $line.Split(':', 2)
        $bucket[$left.Trim()] = $right.Trim()
    }
}

# empty last item to pipeline
[PSCustomObject]$bucket
```

Adjust to taste for identifying numbers, dates, etc.

Second: a multiline regex: I tried, but can't. It would look something like:

```
# Not working, but for example:
$r = @'
Medium identifier    : (?<MediumIdentifier>.*)
\s*
Write-protected      : (?<WriteProtected>.*)
Blocks used  [KB]    : (?<BlockesUsed>.*)
Medium label         : (?<MediumLabel>.*)
Last write           : (?<LastWrite>.*)
Medium Owner         : (?<MediumOwner>.*)
Usable space [KB]    : (?<UsableSpaceKB>.*)
Number of overwrites : (?<NumberOfOverwrites>.*)
Last overwrite       : (?<LastOverwrite>.*)
Medium identifier    : (?<MediumIdentifier>.*)
Blocks total [KB]    : (?<BlocksTotalKB>.*)
Number of errors     : (?<NumberOfErrors>.*)
Medium initialized   : (?<MediumInitialized>.*)
Status               : (?<Status>.*)
Location             : (?<Location>.*)
Protected            : (?<Protected>.*)
Number of writes     : (?<NumberOfWrites>.*)
Last access          : (?<LastAccess>.*)
\s*
'@

[regex]::Matches((get-content C:\work\a.txt -Raw), $r, 
    [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase + 
    [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Singleline
    )
```

Third: `ConvertFrom-String` - http://www.lazywinadmin.com/2014/09/powershell-convertfrom-string-and.html or https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2016/09/14/use-the-new-powershell-cmdlet-convertfrom-string-to-parse-klist-kerberos-ticket-output/ then after you made the template

```
Get-Content data.txt | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateFile .\template.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If each section is in the same format, i.e. the Usable space section is always 5 lines down from the location then you can use the `Select-String` in combination with the context parameter. Something like this:

```
Select-String .\your_file.txt -Pattern '(?<=Location\s*:\s).*' -Context 0, 5 | % {
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        Location = (($_.Matches[0] -replace '\[|\]', '') -split ':')[0]
        UsableSpace = ($_.Context.PostContext[4] -replace '^\D+(\d+)$', '$1' )
    }
}
```